# Assign random date and time slot to user from table

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently building a vaccination appointment program for college and I am trying to write the code to randomly assign a date that ranges anywhere from 1/1/2022-31/12/2022, alongside a time slot ranging from 8am-5pm. Each hour will have 100 slots. Every time a user is assigned a slot, 1 from the assigned slot will be deducted. I tried doing this with a table i built using pandas, but I didn't get very far. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here's my code for the table using pandas (in case it will be helpful):

```
import pandas

start_date = '1/1/2022'
end_date = '31/12/2022'
list_of_date = pandas.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
df = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_date)
df.columns = ['Date/Time']
df['8:00'] = 100
df['9:00'] = 100
df['10:00'] = 100
df['11:00'] = 100
df['12:00'] = 100
df['13:00'] = 100
df['14:00'] = 100
df['15:00'] = 100
df['16:00'] = 100
df['17:00'] = 100
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is start by including the leading zero at the beginning of the hour for each column name. It's easier to extract '08:00' from a pandas Timestamp than '8:00'.

```
df['08:00'] = 100
df['09:00'] = 100
```

Then you can set the index to your `'Date/Time'` column and use `.loc` to locate an appointment slot by the date in the row and the hour (rounded down) in the columns, and subtract 1 from the number of appointments at that slot. For example:

```
df.set_index('Date/Time', inplace=True)
user1_datetime = pd.to_datetime("2022-01-02 08:30")
user1_day = user1_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
user1_time = user1_datetime.floor("h").strftime('%H:%M')
df.loc[user1_day, user1_time] -= 1
```

Result:

```
>>> df
            08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00  14:00  15:00  16:00  17:00
Date/Time                                                                       
2022-01-01    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-01-02     99    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-01-03    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-01-04    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-01-05    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
...           ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
2022-12-27    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-12-28    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-12-29    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-12-30    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
2022-12-31    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100    100
```

To scale up, you can easily wrap this in a function that takes a list of datetimes for multiple people, and checks that the person isn't making an appointment in an hour slot with 0 remaining appointments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Derek. Using what you have given, i've spent the last 24 hours trying to replace line 2 of your code with something that will randomly choose a date and an hour with slots >0. I am only 2 months into python and I still require some assistance. Hope you are willing to help, thank you.

Comment: Update:

I exported the pandas table to a CSV file, and I managed to get the program to open the CSV file and alter the table, then saving it. Any ideas on picking a random date and time though?

Comment: @VIMALRICH you create a list of all the dates and all of the times and then select randomly from each list. for example: `pd.date_range("2022-01-01","2022-12-31")` will give you all of the dates

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Derek, I finally managed to think of a way to do it, and I couldn't have done it without your help. Here's my code:

This builds the table and saves it into a CSV file:

```
import pandas

start_date = '1/1/2022'
end_date = '31/12/2022'
list_of_date = pandas.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
df = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_date)
df.columns = ['Date/Time']
df['8:00'] = 100
df['9:00'] = 100
df['10:00'] = 100
df['11:00'] = 100
df['12:00'] = 100
df['13:00'] = 100
df['14:00'] = 100
df['15:00'] = 100
df['16:00'] = 100
df['17:00'] = 100
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Ric\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\new.csv')
```

And this code randomly pick a date and an hour from that date:

```
import pandas
import random
from random import randrange
#randrange randomly picks an index for date and time for the user
random_date = randrange(365)
random_hour = randrange(10)
list = ["8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00"]
hour = random.choice(list)
df = pandas.read_csv('new.csv')
date=df.iloc[random_date][0]
df.loc[random_date, hour] -= 1
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Rich\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\new.csv',index=False)
print(date)
print(hour)
```

I haven't found a way for the program to check whether the number of slots is > 0 before choosing one though.